# Pandas : more efficient way to do nested for loop plus if

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list, called namelist, with 1000 names and a dataframe, called df_all, with all 1000 names in it but with repeated rows because of different timestamp. Len of df_all is about 2000+.

I want to split this data into individual dataframes.

My code is as follows:

```
df_store = [] 
for i in range(len(namelist)) :
    temp = [] 
    for j in range(len(df_all)):
    if(df_all['name'] == namelist[i]) :
        temp1.append(df_all[j,:]:
        temp_df=pd. DataFrame(temp1).reset_index(drop=1)
    df_store.append(temp_df)
```

This code took 15 mins to loop. I was wonder if there is a way to do this more efficiently?

I needed the df_store to be iterable so that each iterator is a df of a different name.

Comment: Please fix the indentation - currently it makes no sense. Also fix the syntax of `temp1.append(df_all[j,:]:`. In short, make sure the above code is parsed correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run two loops to achieve the results. Pandas DataFrame provides Boolean array Indexing which is pretty fast as well. Please check below:

```
df_store = [] 
for i in range(len(namelist)) :
    temp_df = df_all[df_all.name==namelist[i]].copy()
    df_store.append(temp_df)
```

Here I have used the copy function because the boolean indexing on the df_all will return a view on the df_all and modifying anything in that will impact the same on original df_all.

Hope this helps!!